# Sorting numbers in Java that are saved as a string

Tags: android, sorting, parsing

Lets say I have numbers 1, 2, 11, 21

Logically I want them to order like so;
1, 2, 11, 21

However, they are sorting like so;
1, 11, 2, 21

I am using Parse with their build in ascending order. How can I fix it?

```
 query.addAscendingOrder(ParseConstants.KEY_CREDITOR_DAYDUE);
```

Comment: is it whole string as 1,11,2,21?

Comment: If it's sorting as strings then the answer is correct. Transform type to int or query all and sort on client-side.

Comment: no. they are more like variables in the object. so I am saving information and asking the user to type in a number. When the ParseObject is displayed, I am sorting that object with the number the person enters. The number is from 1-31.

Comment: Could you provide all code, please!

Comment: @IgorB - its a lot of code. I think what I have to do is save the information from the ET as an int instead of a string. I am trying to work on that now.

Answer (score 0):

Be much more specific what you are doing or want to do.

Why would you want to store them as a String.

Else cast/convert them to a int before you store them or after you get them from the query.

But the whole premise of sorting strings as integers is wrong.

You could write your own comparator for this in Java.

But just use the appropriate data type and avoid this kind of hacking.

Answer (score 0):

You might solve this problem without a lot of efforts if it is possible to build your query string with "01", "02","10","13" etc.. Numbers less than 10 with a preciding "0".

If this is not possible than you need to use or make a routine that disassembles your string in individual elements and sort them on their number value.